Is there a way to know which Drush command is executed from within a hook implementation?
Here is my use case.
I'm importing nodes with the classic migration API and goes through some hooks (like hook_node_presave, hook_node_delete...).
I also have another drush command that synchronise content and does some other stuff and goes through those same hooks.
I want to do some specific things in those hooks wether it's called by a back-office action or drush migrate:import or drush command1. Is there a way to pass a context of some sort on the drush command that would be retrievable in my hooks ? Or at least to know the hook is executed by a back-office action ?
I looked there and there but it was not satisfying. Knowing it's executed by PHP_CLI is not precise enough for me in my use case.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991346/in-php-how-to-detect-the-execution-is-from-cli-mode-or-through-browser#2421484

Thanks for your proposal, I'm not really fan of this solution :-)

The question title is "Is there a way to know that I'm executing a drush command on the code side?"

Indeed, but the proposal in the link is not precise enough. I want to know which drush command is executed.

The question needs an edit in that case.

I added some precisions and @4uk4 answer was what I was looking for. I don't get  the downvotes though :'(

It seems to me you should just be creating your own custom Drush command. In that command run the actions that the original Drush command was supposed to run, then add your own follow up to that. I wouldn't use event handlers in this case.

You should be able to get all information from Drush::input() and Drush::getApplication(), but first check if you are running from command line and Drush is installed:
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli' && class_exists('\Drush\Drush')) {
  $command_name = \Drush\Drush::input()->getFirstArgument();
  $full_command_name = \Drush\Drush::getApplication()->find($command_name)->getName();
}


This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but is there a reason you must do those specific things in those hooks as opposed to using the Migrate API Events and Hooks.
It seems those could work and have the context they need about when they are firing.

Thank you for your proposal. In case of migrate command, yes that could be a solution, but I also have another context were I execute my own custom drush command.
